# GridBagLayout: component in multiple grid squares

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, jcomponent

Is it possible to have a single `JComponent` spread over multiple grid squares, and if so how would I achieve this?

Comment: Have you written any code?

Answer (score 4):

Yes its possible.

Read more about [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and find [sample code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java) as well.

In below screenshot **Long-Named Button 4** is spread across 3 columns and **5** in spread across 2 columns.

[image]